# Return increment ng repeat in ng repeat with function angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat and I need to be able to bring the global count of all records.

I have tried declaring a variable in the view within the ng-repeat so that it adds and does not work.

I currently have the following code.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="quotesController">
    <div ng-repeat="info in datos2 track by $index">
      <h2><strong>{{info.name}}</strong></h2>
      <div ng-init='count()' ng-repeat="dato in data track by $index">
        <span>{{dato.name}}</span>
        <br> Position {{id}}
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Code Angular

```
$scope.count=function(){
    number = number + 1; 
    $scope.id=number;  
}
```

I need every ng-repeat query to bring me the number position where it is.

> Example:
>
> Name 1 ITEM 1 - Position 1
>
> ITEM 2 - Position 2
>
> Name 2 ITEM 1  Position 3
>
> ITEM 2  - Position 4
>
> Name 3 ITEM 1  - Position 5
>
> ITEM 2 - Position 6

http://plnkr.co/edit/I5IWOXGmzbu0UNqn04ha?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a global counter from a controller and assign it to a scope variable on each [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) of nested [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) like:

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('quotesController',
  function quotesController($scope) {
    $scope.datos2 = [{
        "name": "Name 1",
      }, {
        "name": "Name 2",
      }, {
        "name": "Name 3",
      }
    ];

    $scope.data = [{
        "name": "ITEM 1",
      }, {
        "name": "ITEM 2",
    }]; 

    var number = 1;
    $scope.count = function(){
        return number++; 
    }

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="quotesController">
    
    <div ng-repeat="info in datos2 track by $index">
      <h2><strong>{{info.name}}</strong></h2>
      <div ng-init='id = count()' ng-repeat="dato in data track by $index">
        <span>{{dato.name}}</span>
        <br> Position {{id}}
        <br />
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ngInit for this.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="quotesController" ng-init="totalCount = 1">
    <div ng-repeat="info in datos2 track by $index">
      <h2><strong>{{info.name}}</strong></h2>
      <div ng-repeat="dato in data track by $index" ng-init="position = totalCount++">
        <span>{{dato.name}}</span>
        <br> Position {{position}}
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Original would have had all items with same position value.

Comment: @JCFord There is already one `ng-init='count()'`, so the second one will not work: http://plnkr.co/edit/6xTnOc9KOxpB4gEDE1lA?p=preview

Comment: Hmm. Maybe angular's parser doesn't like the unary operator. Try `position = totalCount = totalCount + 1`

Comment: @StanislavKvitash oh I didn't notice he already had one. Should just remove that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{($parent.$index*data.length)+($index+1)}}`

```
<div ng-repeat="info in datos2 track by $index">
  <h2><strong>{{info.name}}</strong></h2>
  <div ng-init='count()' ng-repeat="dato in data track by $index">
     <span>{{dato.name}}</span>
     <br> Position {{($parent.$index*data.length)+($index+1)}}
     <br />
     <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0mcgZfxmL5PBwSDp0hoo?p=preview